# How to prove that f is one-to-one

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g\colon \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with bounded derivative. i.e. $|g'(x)| < M$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon$ be a positive number satisfying $0 < \epsilon < 1/M$. Let $f(x) = x+\epsilon g(x)$.

How can I prove that $f$ is one-to-one (injective)? I really have no idea how to solve hint. Any hint would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Now think about applying the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Our task is to show that $x=y$.

We have that $0=f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)+\epsilon(g(x)-g(y))$. Using the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), we  know that there is some $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $g(x)-g(y)=(x-y)g'(z)$, so $$0=f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)(1+\epsilon g'(z)).$$ Now, if $x\ne y$, then $1+\epsilon g'(z)=0$, or $g'(z)=-1/\epsilon<-M$, so $|g'(z)|>M$, contradicting the given estimate. Since this is impossible, then $x=y$, as we needed.

Answer (score 2):

By contradiction : Suppose that exists $x,y$  such that $x < y$  and $f(x)=f(y)$ then  $x+\epsilon g(x)=y+\epsilon g(y)$ ie  $x-y=\epsilon (g(y)-g(x)) = \epsilon (y-x) g'(c)$  where  $x < c < y$ ($c$ exists by Mean Value Theorem). So : $|x-y|=\epsilon |g'(c)| |x-y| \leq \epsilon M |x-y| < |x-y|$

That is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, what can you say about $f'(x)$ for $x\in(x_1,x_2)$?